# Windows 7/ Lenovo PC

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I just wondered if anyone could give me advice on swapping some computer parts over. I've always wanted to build my own PC so I bought a 2TB hard drive and a tower in last months pay. My girlfriends parents are getting rid of their old PC maybe about 3 years old but has Windows 7 installed on it with Microsoft office (Both of which I want). There is hardly anything on it, and it will be easy to rest to factory settings etc and I have extracted the windows code for reinstall.

So what I want to do is take out the other parts of the machine like CPU, power supply, motherboard etc and install it into my new computer tower and install my 2TB hard drive.

Questions are: what happens to the OS? I want to keep the OS and MO but I want it on my new 2TB HD, as far as I understood it's on the original computer hard drive but in the past I've updated HD's and can't for the life of me remember how I got the contents and OS off of the existing HD.

My other question is, as I am only replacing the HD will everything else in the machine be compatible with it?

If anyone can explain to me the correct way of transferring the OS system over to my new HD and if there will be any problems from moving tower cases and replacing HD's.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could clone the hard drive with the OS to your new 2TB HD. There are many different softwares out there that providing cloning. There will not be any problem replacing HDs. Depending on the size of the motherboard you could change tower cases as well without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Boot the old computer and extract all relevant information.
   Then build the new computer with the 2TB drive, install a fresh copy of windows (e.g. using the old computers CoA), install a clean office etc etc.
   Result: a clean, fresh installation without leftover cruft. Best you can hope for.
2. Make copy of the old hard drive using Acronis, Norton ghost or a similar program<sup>*1</sup>. YOu now have a copy of the activated OS, office (also activated) etc etc. Least amounth of work, but:
   *. You also inherit all leftovers from the previous owner
   *. Depending on the original copies this might not be legal.

The clarify the last two parts:
Some windows licences are for specific hardware only. E.g. to be sold with one specific system. You cannot legally move that to a new PC.
Office: Ditto. Could be a legal copy, could be a 'install once and pay again next time'. Could be registered to an account of the previous owner.

Without knowing more details of the old system it is hard to say if any of these are the case.

Worst case: You either need to take the old machine (maybe upgrade it part by part and phone microsoft everytime too much changes and clean a failed motherboard and say that you replaced it), or you would need to buy legal copies.  Win7 or win10 will set you back about 30 euros. Office about 100 euros<sup>*2</sup>

Having written all that. I recommend setting up a nice clean computer first and playing around with it. You can install windows without a key. It will only work for 30 days<sup>*3</sup>, but you can learn a lot by just installing it and playing around, seeing how the sytem acti different. Try one big partition. Try three (OS, data, backup). Play with backupos and images. Then when you feel you have learned everything you wanted decide on one final install.

<sup>So much for a long winded way of answering `If anyone can explain to me the correct way of transferring the OS system over to my new HD`</sup>

`and if there will be any problems from moving tower cases and replacing HD`

Moving a case is trivial. I assume you also mean moving to a new motherboard. Which is not. You can be lucky and it will work. Or it might not even boot. Search the many posts on "cloning" and doing a sysprep before the cloning. That part is answered in existing post on [SU] and I am skimping over it and only mentioning the search terms.

---

<sup>*1</sup> There are dozens of ways to do this. I just mentioned the two I have the most experience with.

<sup>*2</sup> The 100 euro mentioned for office was the best I could find for office 2016 prof. (with access). Student version can be cheaper. Full versions at reatil price can easily be 3 or 4 times as expensive.

*3 At least without rearm tricks.

Comment: You left out the possibility of significantly different low-level hardware (particularly the storage controller), which would cause the "new" system to get stuck in a reboot loop. I don't know if Acronis or Norton Ghost has a migration feature for handling this, but Paragon does offer one. It clears out the low-level drivers Windows is configured to use and lets Windows redetect the hardware. An alternative is to use the Windows recovery from the Windows installation cd to run a startup repair. Your answer would be perfect if not for that.

Comment: Old ones did not. I used to 1, Make a clean image. 2. Boot the old compuyer, remove cruft (e.g. wireless drivers, old programs, ...) and then sysprep generallise. 3). Image again. 4) Install and boot this clean image on the new system. Most of the time this worked. Often additonal drivers 'Press F6 and insert floppy' was needed. .... This was noron 8.3 time, so long ago. Cavemen era, when XP once ruled.

Comment: XP was the first consumer Windows to have this problem. But all the Window NT-based OSes since at least Windows 2000 have this problem. I'm not sure about NT4 and earlier. The Windows 9x-es (Windows 95-ME) generally did not have this problem. Or rather, they did... but they had a catch-all generic driver that would work with all non-raid storage controllers of its day that would let you at least get into windows so you could install the correct ones.